# Add QSpinBox to a child of QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qspinbox

I know how to add a `QSpinBox` to a `QTreeWidgetItem` :

```
_spin_speed = new QSpinBox();
ui->treeWidget->setItemWidget(ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(0) , 1 , _spin_sizePicture);
```

But how to add a `QSpinBox` to a child of `QTreeWidgetItem`? By "child" I mean this Item in particular :
[image]

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
 _spin_angle = new QSpinBox();    
 ui->treeWidget->setItemWidget(ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(2)->treeWidget()->topLevelItem(0) , 1 , _spin_angle);
```

Thanks for your time, and have a great day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

topLevelItem() gets a top level item. What you need is child():

```
 ui->treeWidget->setItemWidget(ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(2)->child(0) , 1 , _spin_angle);
```